# Can you use "query" to begin a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

The following sentence uses query at the beginning of a sentence:

> Query when is it ever good time.

Am I using *query* correctly. I am trying to say "I question whether..."

Comment: "Query and it shall be given to you."  Or, perhaps a bit more meaningful, "Query and he will respond."

Comment: I distinctly recall Detective Ironside from the U.S. TV series _Ironside_ framing questions on multiple occasions as (for example) "Query: Why would the murderer have left back door open?" I remember this because it was an unusual form of expression and because the show's writers liked it enough to make it one of the lead character's verbal quirks.

Comment: "Query not what your country can do for you ..."

Comment: The sense of the word in the way Ironside is quoted as using it, is a spoken form of the way it was used in taking notes. The note-taker would write 'Query: ' as a reminder to look up some information or do further research when the opportunity arose..

Comment: "Query the database." It's a command, and one you'd possibly hear in a really bad 70s movie about computer crime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*I* query when it is....(ever a good time)" would be a correct sentence.
Or: "I query when it will ever be a good time" <- sounds better to me.

Query is both a noun and verb:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/query

But it needs an I/you etc.
Or did you mean to use it as an imperative?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using *"query"* correctly in your example, given your intended meaning. However, *"query"* can begin a sentence.

The implied subject, when *"query"* begins a sentence as a verb, is *"you"*. I think it may be easier to use *"ask"* to demonstrate:
*"Ask me this: what measures have I taken?"*
Insert *"query"*, and you have a less common usage, but still understandable. This is why your example usage is incorrect, as the meaning you want, i.e. ***"I question whether"***, is not what your example sentence would mean: ***"You question when it would be a good time."***.

As a noun, *"query"* is a direct substitute for *"question"*.